# How avoid issues with WLAN?

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

I've got a 2 months old Laptop with Kubuntu 22.04 ThinkPad T16 Gen 1 (16" AMD).

```
uname -a
Linux tp-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-1 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Sometimes (several times per day or just 1 - 2 times per week) my WLAN doesn't work anymore. In those cases, I seem to be connected to my network but with 0 up and down traffic. There are usually 5 wireless networks visible in my network widget (close to the clock, bottom right). When the network doesn't work anymore, there is only the connected on.
If I disconnect, there are no visible networks anymore.

A normal reboot takes around 30 sec or so.
A reboot during having this problem here, takes around 3 minutes.
I see hundreds of entries here:

```
journalctl -rb -1
Feb 13 04:19:25 tp-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-1 systemd-resolved[1156]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server fd00::3a10:d5ff:fe7b:7647.
Feb 13 04:19:24 tp-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-1 kernel: ath11k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to transmit frame -108
Feb 13 04:19:24 tp-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-1 kernel: ath11k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to transmit frame -108
Feb 13 04:19:24 tp-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-1 kernel: ath11k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to transmit frame -108
```

Network / house details:

- There are two floors, the router is in the room directly below me (about 2m as the crow flies, certainly with reinforced concrete in between).
- The repeater is in the hallway (approx. 4m as the crow flies, only one wall/room door in between)
- Router: FRITZ!Box 7362 SL
- Repeater: FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 1750E
- I use the standard WiFi, guest WiFi is switched off on repeater
- I only connect 2-3 devices (2 laptops, 1 mobile phone) to the router directly from the room via the router
- The remaining devices on the upper floor are connected to the repeater (reason: repeater is near the microwave and when it is on, WiFi no longer works)

When I'm in a longer session and it suddently doesn't work anymore, I see:

```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WiFi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 38:10:D5:7B:76:49   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

sudo ps aux | grep -i [w]pa
root        1334  0.0  0.0  17668 11368 ?        Ss   Jan31   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

sudo dmesg | grep -iE 'auth|assoc'
[28635.615024] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[28643.171887] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49
[28643.210043] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[28643.323176] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 2/3)
[28643.329680] wlp2s0: authenticated
[28643.335189] wlp2s0: associate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[28643.343390] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[28643.354499] wlp2s0: associated
[31668.532378] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[31676.241665] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49
[31676.280509] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[31676.287750] wlp2s0: authenticated
[31676.291177] wlp2s0: associate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[31676.301025] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=7)
[31676.320972] wlp2s0: associated
```

When I restart and it doesn't work anymore after 3 minutes, it looks slightly different:

```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WiFi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point:  38:10:D5:7B:76:49    
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

sudo ps aux | grep -i [w]pa
root        1273  0.0  0.0  17556 10908 ?        Ss   17:08   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

sudo dmesg | grep -iE 'auth|assoc'
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.748351] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: ad91990bc22ab1f517048c23b6655a268e345a63'
[    8.153662] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49
[    8.283511] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[    8.294054] wlp2s0: authenticated
[    8.296879] wlp2s0: associate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[    8.306973] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=3)
[    8.323293] wlp2s0: associated
```

When everything works, it looks like:

```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WiFi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 38:10:D5:7B:76:49   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:177  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

veth39ed50a  no wireless extensions.

sudo ps aux | grep -i [w]pa
root        1265  0.0  0.0  17692 11500 ?        Ss   Feb01   0:01 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

sudo dmesg | grep -iE 'auth|assoc'
[11280.135071] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[11287.761700] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49
[11287.815254] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[11287.822374] wlp2s0: authenticated
[11287.827145] wlp2s0: associate with 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (try 1/3)
[11287.838129] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:10:d5:7b:76:49 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=3)
[11287.853386] wlp2s0: associated
```

Currently, I need to reboot to reactivate my network.
This: `sudo service NetworkManager restart`
does not help.

Hope someone knows how to fix the problem.
Alternatively: How can I avoid the reboot?

Comment: What is the kernel version? `uname -a`

Comment: I've added the info to the top of the question

Comment: Now the 5.19 kernel is available. Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` and reboot. This may be fixed there.

Comment: Done, thanks. I'll keep an eye on it.